# JSF navigation in a HTML DIV element without reloading the entire page

Tags: ajax, jsf, menu

I would like to know if it's possible to make JSF navigation rules inside a `<div>` without reloading the entire page, in an Ajax fashion (like as in Gmail).

Suppose you have your application main page with this situation:

```
<div id="main"> 
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="menu"></div>
  <div id="content"> 
    (JSF navigation inside this div)
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for reply.

Answer (score 2):

[JSF 2.0](http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/) has built-in ajax-functionality.

If working with JSF 1.2 - [RichFaces](http://www.jboss.org/richfaces) provides such ajax functionality, using the `reRender` attribute which specifies which parts of the page to redisplay.